# Linux namespace issue

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I am stuck with a network namespace issue.  I have a script which sets up a namespace.  It works on one Linux box but not the other.

The script:

```
function iface_up() {
  ip netns add riatans

  ip netns exec riatans ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
  ip netns exec riatans ip link set lo up

  ip link add riatavpn type veth peer name vpn1
  ip link set riatavpn up
  ip link set vpn1 netns riatans up

  ip addr add 10.211.211.1/24 dev riatavpn
  ip netns exec riatans ip addr add 10.211.211.2/24 dev vpn1
  ip netns exec riatans ip route add default via 10.211.211.1 dev vpn1

  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $if_name -j MASQUERADE
  iptables -A FORWARD -i $if_name -o riatavpn -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i riatavpn -o $if_name -j ACCEPT

  sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

  mkdir -p /etc/netns/riatans
  echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/netns/riatans/resolv.conf

  ip netns exec riatans ping -c 1 www.google.com
}
```

On the box it works.

```
# ip netns list
riatans (id: 0)
# ip netns exec riatans ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.12.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s62-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=12.3 ms
# ip netns exec riatans traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.12.164), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.211.211.1 (10.211.211.1)  0.064 ms  0.019 ms  0.015 ms
 2  10.7.7.1 (10.7.7.1)  0.360 ms  0.506 ms  0.461 ms
# ip netns exec riatans ip route
default via 10.211.211.1 dev vpn1 
10.211.211.0/24 dev vpn1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.211.211.2
```

On the box that doesn't work:

```
# ip netns list
riatans (id: 0)
# ip netns exec riatans ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.7.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s56-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.7.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=36.3 ms
64 bytes from lga25s56-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.7.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=19.1 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.158/27.776/36.394/8.618 ms
# ip netns exec riatans traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.7.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.211.211.1 (10.211.211.1)  0.029 ms  0.008 ms  0.007 ms
 2  10.211.211.1 (10.211.211.1)  0.010 ms !X  0.008 ms !X  0.008 ms !X
# ip netns exec riatans ip route
default via 10.211.211.1 dev vpn1 
10.211.211.0/24 dev vpn1 proto kernel scope link src 10.211.211.2
```

I should mention that on box 2, outside of namespace, Internet works fine.  So while box 2 can ping www.google.com inside namespace riatans but can't do traceroute, ssh or vpnc.

What am I missing?  Why is the traceroute 2nd hop not 10.7.7.1 (my router)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceroute by default uses UDP packets, so the ping can works, but traceroute output can be differect.

The `!X` from the `10.211.211.1` host in the traceroute output means the ICMP `communication administrative prohibited` answer.

This is a firewall issue. Check the full rule set with `iptables-save` command.

When you configure the firewall rules for network namespace, you add the rules at the bottom of chains. Rules at the top of chains can block the UDP packets from your additional namespace.

Comment: You are right on.  I disabled firewall and it worked.  Now that I think about it, box 1 is openSUSE LEAP 43.2 which uses old SuSEfirewall and box 2 is LEAP 15 which has transitioned to firewalld.  It must have been what firewalld is doing that SuSEfirewall wasn't.  Obviously I don't want to leave firewalld disabled.  What rule should I add?  Inside namespace, I am using 10.211.211.* and on the OS, my subnet is 10.7.0.0/16.  What am I opening on the firewall?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Your rules are correct, but placed in the wrong position. The simplest way is just replace `-A` to `-I` to insert rules to the top of chains. The correct way is investigate the current rule set organization and the firewalld, and use the firewalld commands to allow packets from the namespace.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing.  That fixed it.